# Python changes are not reflected

Tags: python

I have a example.py file. loaded on a linux server. I put some prints in this file and saved it. 
When I call this .py file I am not getting these changes.

Do I need to do something (Like for C we need to compile the .c file and put the .so to LD_LIBRARY_PATH) for python also.

Thanks,

Comment: please provide your "example.py" code. Foult may lie not in the refreshing the file but in where and how those prints are used.

Comment: Are you in a python interactive session (trying to execute the script from within python) or calling from the command line (`python example.py`)? If the first, you need to [reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) the module.

Comment: nothing of that sort is required. Just call python filename and start with reading a good tutorial please.

Comment: How we can reload this module once changed. I am calling a function of it from from other python file in which this is imported.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a example.py file. loaded on a linux server.

Many linux servers including Apache and Nginx load the files they need to serve when they start for performance sake. So, you may need to restart the server to pickup the latest python file.